# SQLSTATE [IM004]: [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Driver SQLAllocHandle with SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I ran into this error on the rental server.

I investigated a lot, but every question is a question on the local server.

I can't connect to SSH and I don't have the authority to operate the control panel.

Please let me know how to solve the error in this situation

This is error message:

> SQLSTATE [IM004]: [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Driver SQLAllocHandle with SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed.

Comment: @Saly3301 In other words, you have to ask the administrator.

Comment: @Saly3301 I do n’t have enough knowledge so I ’d like you to explain in more detail

Comment: Laravel is not made for shared hosting (rental service), because it expects root priveledges to configure PHP and its extensions and database drivers and run npm and set the root to /public and symlink to storage <=== all of these are not possible on shared hosting

Comment: @Saly3301 It's .... worried about what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the rental server company and reinstalled the driver.